# Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

I'm using Maven for my web application but when I run mvn clean install I get

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.144 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-05T20:19:13+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/271M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project HW-web-parent: Error assembling WA
R: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
```

My main maven looks like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>shop.tryHW</groupId>
    <artifactId>tryHW-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>tryHW-core</module>
        <module>tryHW-web</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>2.5</log4j.version>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <hamcrest-all.version>1.3</hamcrest-all.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.5.0</dbunit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- ======= -->
            <!-- Logging -->
            <!-- ======= -->
            <!-- SLF4J -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Apache Log4j 2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- ======= -->
            <!-- Testing -->
            <!-- ======= -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>${mockito.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>${hamcrest-all.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
                <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- Logging -->
        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Log4j 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- Testing -->
        <!-- ======= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

I looked over solutions online and they were saying to add the  under configurations but it's not working. Any ideas? I already have a WEB-INF/web.xml with the path tryHW\tryHW-web\web\WEB-INF\web.xml

Comment: So, do you have a `web.xml` or not for your WAR project, which I guess is `tryHW-web`?

Comment: I do have a web.xml. I will post the code if necessary

Comment: And is it correctly under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`?

Comment: I have it in 2 places, just to make sure: D:\Projects\Java\tryHW\tryHW-web\web\WEB-INF and D:\Projects\Java\tryHW\webapp\WEB-INF

Comment: Both are wrong then. It should be  `D:\Projects\Java\tryHW\tryHW-web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF`. Please follow the Maven conventions https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: It worked! Thank you very very much!